# How often do I need to draw until all balls in an Urn are of the same color?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose there is an Urn with $n$ balls, $m$ being white and $(n-m)$ being black.

Now we draw $c, c < n$ balls - any white ball drawn will be colored black - then we put all balls back into the Urn and repeat.

How often do we need to draw until we expect all balls to be black?

//-
More clearly: how often do I need to draw until 95% of the white balls are colored in black?

Comment: Forget about the colors, there are $m$ special balls, and we repeat our draws until we have drawn each of them at least once.

Comment: What is the exact meaning of "we expect all balls to be black"? Probability over $\frac12$? Probability one?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta : I need a finite solution: e.g. when are 95% of the former white balls black. Sorry for being unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected number of draws to choose a white ball given there are $m$ of them is $\frac{n}{m}$, and now we must choose one of the $m-1$ remaining white balls, etc. until there are none left so the expected number of draws is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{n}{i}=nH_m$$